# How to connect integer values (ID Number) with cv::Point2f (Points of the found Marker)

Tags: c++, opencv

I work with ArUco Markers and get back the found corners and the ID number of a marker independently. I need to connect the ID (int) and the corners (cv::Point2f or cv::Mat) in order to work with the corners of specific ID numbers.

The ID from the first found Marker:
int ID =  _ids.getMat().ptr< int >(0)[0];

The corners from the first Marker:
Mat corners = _corners.getMat(0);

How to connect them in order to search for a ID number and get the cornes of this ID?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy. The order of marker ids and positions is the same:

http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d6a/group__aruco.html#ga306791ee1aab1513bc2c2b40d774f370

If you have corners and ids stored in std::vectors you could use:

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> findMarker(const std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> &_points, 
                                    const std::vector<int> &indices, int _id)
{
  for(auto &i:indices)
    {
      if(i==_id) return _points(&i-&indices[0]);
    }
  return std::vector<cv::Point2f>(0);
}
```